# Help with Understanding Independent Events

Tags: probability, independence

This is a question from MIT 6.041 open courseware.

Most mornings, Victor checks the weather report before deciding whether to carry an umbrella. If the forecast is “rain,” the probability of actually having rain that day is 80%. On the other hand, if the forecast is “no rain,” the probability of it actually raining is equal to 10%. During fall and winter the forecast is “rain” 70% of the time and during summer and spring it is 20%.

(a) One day, Victor missed the forecast and it rained. What is the probability that the forecast was “rain” if it was during the winter? What is the probability that the forecast was “rain” if it was during the summer?

(b) The probability of Victor missing the morning forecast is equal to 0.2 on any day in the year. If he misses the forecast, Victor will flip a fair coin to decide whether to carry an umbrella. On any day of a given season he sees the forecast, if it says “rain” he will always carry an umbrella, and if it says “no rain,” he will not carry an umbrella. Are the events “Victor is carrying an umbrella,” and “The forecast is no rain” independent? Does your answer depend on the season??

I need some help understanding the solution for part b.

Let A: Victory is carrying an umbrella
and B: The forecast is no rain

The solution posits that if A and B are independent, then P(A) = P(A|B).
Since P(A) = .1 + .8p (miss and umbrella + not miss and umbrella) and
P(A|B) = .1 + .8(0), A and B are independent IFF p = 0 where p is the probability of the forecast being "rain".

I get the rationale... but how do I, analytically, get P(A|B) = .1 + .8(0)? I can't seem to get to this equation regardless of which equivalent statements I sub in and algebra around.

Here is the exact text from the solution:

> P(C | D) = (0.8)(0) + (0.2)(0.5) = 0.1
> Therefore, P(C) = P(C | D) if
> and only if p = 0. However, p can only be 0.7 or 0.2, which implies
> the events C and D can never be independent, and this result does not
> depend on the season.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

They're using total probability and conditioning both $A$ and $(A|B)$ on event $M$, Victor missing the forecast. $P(M)=0.2$ and $P(M^C)=1-0.2=0.8$. Then,

$P(A)=P(A|M)P(M)+P(A|M^C)P(M^C)=(0.5)(0.2)+p(0.8)$

$P(A|M)$ is the probability he grabs an umbrella given he misses the forecast, i.e., the outcome of the fair coin toss. If he catches the forecast (event $M^C$), the probability he grabs an umbrella equals the probability $p$ that the forecast calls for rain.

$P(A|B)$ also depends on whether he misses the forecast, with the slight difference that the $|B$ means we are only considering days where no rain is actually forecast, i.e., if he catches the forecast, he will not grab an umbrella.

$P(A|B)=P[(A|B)|M]P(M)+P[(A|B)|M^C]P(M^C)=(0.5)(0.2)+(0)(0.8)$

That's why they're saying that for $P(A)=P(A|B)$, $p$ must equal 0, which it won't in any season. So, every single day of the year, $p\neq 0$ which destroys independence according to the formal definition.

Intuitively, this result makes sense because Victor grabbing his umbrella based on the forecast—when he remembers to watch it—ties the events together. The only possible way independence could exist under that paradigm is if the news never called for rain. Then, umbrella use would always correspond to other events (forgetting to tune in and then flipping a coin).